# How to make my if statement run code within the statement after the result is produced?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have an if (else) statement in my code and but when I attempt to execute the code it does not run, but I do not get a notification that there is a syntax error etc. I think I  may be missing something but I am not sure what...

This is my current code:

```
    NewUserOrOldUser= input ("Have you played this game before?")
    if NewUserOrOldUser is "yes":
    VerifyUn= input("Please enter the username you chose")
    VerifyPw= input("Please enter the password you chose")
    VerfifyUnPw= VerfiyUn + VerifyPw
    if VerifyUnPw in open("Un & Pw").read():
        print ("Proceed")
     else:
        print ("The data you inputted was incorrect, please try again")`
if NewUserOrOldUser is "no":
```

This is what happens when I run the code:
[image of my what happens when my code runs, the first question is asked but nothing happens after that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuVFF.png)

Comment: `if NewUserOrOldUser is "yes":` Use `==`. [Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/132988)

Comment: Also please read: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help And [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `if NewUserOrOldUser is "yes":`
To make your code run use `if NewUserOrOldUser == "yes":`

Also remove the last else block or put code there.

```
NewUserOrOldUser= input ("Have you played this game before?")
if NewUserOrOldUser == "yes":
    VerifyUn= input("Please enter the username you chose")
    VerifyPw= input("Please enter the password you chose")
    VerfifyUnPw= VerfiyUn + VerifyPw
    if VerifyUnPw in open("Un & Pw").read():
        print ("Proceed")
    else:
        print ("The data you inputted was incorrect, please try again")
```